# How can i get error at compile, not runtime. eg: regexp.MustCompile

Tags: go, compilation

- I am writing golang program and use function regexp.MustComplile. but it may be panic at some time you don't know
- just like `regexp.MustCompile("Expressions John.Smith will cause panic but you don't known").`
- I want got error during compilation , not at the runtime.
- Is there any way to make that report an error during compilation?
- thanks for your help

Comment: I am thinking about we can write makefile to do this, look's like need code generateor or something else

Comment: I would strongly recommend just writing a unit test to validate the expressions and their usage, and executing tests as part of your build process.

Comment: @Adrian yes, it make sense

Answer (score 1):

`regexp.MustCompile()` is a function that can only run at runtime, so you can't make a compile-time error using it. The most you can do is call it from a package `init()` function (or use it in a global variable initialization), so the error will be detected early, at the start of your program.

Generally, you can't validate strings (semantically) at compile time (whether they fulfill your custom, arbitrary rules).

Best practice is to write unit tests for these things, unit tests which should always run as part of your CI process, so these things surface before your code goes to production.

Comment: But if I do not implement some interface, it will report an error when compiling. Is this the same

Comment: No, it's not the same. The compiler can check if a type implements an interface, but the compiler won't check the content of your (valid) `string` literals.

Comment: Can I modify the compiler or add plug-ins to do this? If it's possiable

Comment: @yqw Go is open source, you may modify its sources to detect such things at compile time. Is it worth it? No, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your help,  i will consider about it.